# create an automake target that is a hard link to another target

Tags: autoconf, automake

I have a system that creates 5 executables. All executables are really the same program, but they are all hard links to the same file. I don't know how to do this cleanly with automake. Is there a way? I have no problem actually making the files---but they don't get installed properly. I'm kind of dumbfounded on how to set this up.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you really need hard links? What's wrong with symlinks?

Comment: Good question; I've always used hard links for executables. Does every file system now suport symlinks?

Comment: No, I don't think so, but you can use autoconf's `AC_PROG_LN_S` and then use `$(LN_S)` in your `Makefile.am` rules. That will cause `$(LN_S)` to fall back to `cp` if it doesn't support symlinks.

Comment: Thanks. But MacOS still distributes with hard links for executables in the `bin` directories. Symlinks are only used between top-level directories, like from `/usr/bin` to `/Library`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define `install-exec-hook` and `uninstall-hook`. See [extending](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/automake/Extending.html) in the automake manual.

Comment: Note that for uninstallation you need to use `uninstall-hook`, not `uninstall-exec-hook`.